# How to split up PHP array so each value can be accessed

Tags: php, arrays

I am reading from a file using PHP:

```
$file = file('myfile.txt');
```

This stores each line in the line as a separate value in the array.

myfile.txt

```
123-12333 : Example
456-45666 : MyWorld
```

This result is:

```
Array( [0] => 123-12333 : Example [1] => 456-45666 : MyWorld)
```

I need to split up each individual index value so that my result would end up being something like this:

```
Array([0] => 123-12333 [1] => : [2] => Example [3] => 456-45666 [4] => : [5] => MyWorld)
```

I need to split up the array so that each value can be accessed independently.

array_chunk doesn't seem to work, and array_slice won't help either. Any suggestions??

Things I have tried is:

```
 print_r(array_chunk($fileContents,2));
```

result:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 123-12333 : Duan Uys [1] => 345-34555 : Dennis Taylor ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 555-55555 : Darwin Award ) )
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried.

Comment: `array_walk($file, function(&$value) { $value = explode(' ', $value); })` might be a starting point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
$file     = file('myfile.txt');
$splitted = array();
foreach ($file as $line) {
    $splitted = array_merge($splitted, explode(' ', $line));
}
//now $splitted will have the format you need
```

Comment: What about splitting on `' : '`, splitting on a space will give them 3 entries as opposed to 2 expected

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky The OP actually wants `:` to be stored as a separate value (i.e. `Array([0] => 123-12333 [1] => : ...)`) though I don't know why this would be useful...

Comment: I need to isolate the 123-12333, thats why i need them to be all seperated. Thank you @waldson this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

myfile.txt:

```
123-12333 : Example
456-45666 : MyWorld
```

PHP:

```
$file = 'myfile.txt';
$content = file_get_contents($file);
$lines = explode("\n", $content);
$returnArray = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $returnArray[] = explode(' ', $line);
}

print_r($returnArray);
```

As you mentioned in a comment you needed the first part. To get this, change:

```
$returnArray[] = explode(' ', $line);
```

to:

```
$returnArray[] = current(explode(' ', $line));
```

Comment: Your $returnArray will only contain the last line data. You're overwriting it on every loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass each part to a variable as a string, then split in with ":" dilimiter and then put it in an array like this:

```
$output=array();
foreach ($input as $key=>$value){
    $output[$key][]=substr($value,0,strpos($value,' : '));
    $output[$key][]=substr($value,strpos($value,' : ')+3,strlen($value));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about some [`fscanf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fscanf.php) action... this is pretty much how it's intended to be used:

```
$handle = fopen("myfile.txt", "r");
$lines = array();

while ($line = fscanf($handle, "%s : %s\n")) {
    array_merge($lines, $line);   
}

fclose($handle);
```

That will omit the colon, but I don't think that's useful since you say:

> I need to isolate the 123-12333, thats why i need them to be all seperated.

This is very similar to the other approaches using `file` and then looping over and modifying things but it has the added bonus of reading the file line by line so that the whole thing isn't in memory first. This won't matter if your file is pretty small but it could if this file is large or will get larger over time. Additionally if you only want the number then you can just do:

```
$handle = fopen("myfile.txt", "r");
$numbers = array();

while ($line = fscanf($handle, "%s : %s\n")) {
   $numbers[] = $line[0]; 
}

fclose($handle);
```